# hover on one link change the color of the link itself and of another one (and viceversa)

Tags: html, css, mousehover

I've the following problem (probably it could be solve easily, let's see :))

```css
.title:hover ~ .intro a {color:red;}
.title a:hover, .intro a:hover{color:red;}
```

```html
<div class="gri">

 <p>don't change me</p>

   <div class="title">
    <h3><a href="http://google.com">title</a></h3>
   </div>

<h2>don't change me</h2>

  <div class="intro">
   <a href="http://google.com" class="excerpt">intro text blah blah</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Only using CSS and not changing the HTML code, how can I reach the following:

hover on the "title" results in the title becoming red and also the intro. Same for the intro (hover on the intro, the intro and the title become red).

Any suggestion? 
I already tried different CSS combinations, but it led to nowhere.

Thank you

David

Comment: could you please provide the CSS?

Comment: Hi, I added an example of a (partially working) css in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp

- targets adjacent sibling selector
  ~ is used for general sibling selector

however, adjacent means "immediately following", [there's no equivalent for previous sibling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector). Therefore you can't do this using pure CSS.

You'll need to use javascript in this case, or refactor the way HTML is structured.