# jquery :hover change two elements when hovering one of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-hover, onhover

super jquery beginner here.

I somehow came to this. When hovering the heading I'd like to change the background of the excerpt too ... and viceversa (when hovering the excerpt the background of the heading will change too).

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".heading, .excerpt").hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('is-hover'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('is-hover'); });

});
```

```css
.heading.is-hover{background-color: red;}
.excerpt.is-hover{background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <header class="heading"><h2>CIAO</h2></header>
   <div>don't change me</div>
   <div class="excerpt">text text text</div>
   </div>




<div>
   <header class="heading"><h2>hi!</h2></header>
   <div>don't change me</div>
   <div class="excerpt">text two text two</div>
</div>
```

How can I go on from here? I'm kind of stuck.

I can't change the html part, so no pure css (the question is somehow related my other one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66602370/hover-on-one-link-change-the-color-of-the-link-itself-and-of-another-one-and-vi)).

thank you for your help & suggestions!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a combination of events: `mouseover` and `mouseleave` and jQuery's `.prevAll` and `.nextAll` and the `:first` css selector to color the corresponding header/excerpt or remove it

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".heading").on('mouseover', function() { 
      $(this).addClass('is-hover');
      $(this).nextAll('.excerpt:first').addClass('is-hover');
  });
  
  $(".excerpt").on('mouseover', function() {
      $(this).addClass('is-hover');
      $(this).prevAll('.heading:first').addClass('is-hover');
  });
  
  $(".heading").on('mouseleave', function() { 
      $(this).removeClass('is-hover');
      $(this).nextAll('.excerpt:first').removeClass('is-hover');
  });
  
  $(".excerpt").on('mouseleave', function() {
      $(this).removeClass('is-hover');
      $(this).prevAll('.heading:first').removeClass('is-hover');
  });

});
```

```css
.heading.is-hover{background-color: red;}
.excerpt.is-hover{background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <header class="heading"><h2>CIAO</h2></header>
   <div>don't change me</div>
   <div class="excerpt">text text text</div>
   </div>




<div>
   <header class="heading"><h2>hi!</h2></header>
   <div>don't change me</div>
   <div class="excerpt">text two text two</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. The code you posted only works if the two elements are next to each-other, right? What if there's something in between that doesn't have to change on hover? (see my updated example) ... that's why I was using (this), but I'm not sure on how to "link" the element referred in (this) with the other that has to change.

Comment: @Dande See updated answer. Changed to using a combination of `prevAll` and `nextAll` with `:first`, now it does what you asked. You should have included the fact that you had an element in between when you posted, that was important information.

Comment: Hi Ryan, you're right. Thank you, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Just target those sibling classes.
This one will only work according to your initial request. The below one will maybe work for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".heading").hover(
    function() { $(this).addClass('is-hover').siblings('.excerpt').addClass('is-hover'); },
        function() { $(this).removeClass('is-hover').siblings('.excerpt').removeClass('is-hover'); });

});
```

```css
.heading.is-hover{background-color: red;}
.excerpt.is-hover{background-color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <header class="heading"><h2>CIAO</h2></header>
   <div>don't change me</div>
   <div class="excerpt">text text text</div>
   </div>




<div>
   <header class="heading"><h2>hi!</h2></header>
   <div>don't change me</div>
   <div class="excerpt">text two text two</div>
</div>
```

Or simply add a global class to the wrapping `div`

```js
$('.heading').closest('div').addClass('hover-block');

$('.hover-block').hover(function() {
  $(this).addClass('is-hover');
}, function(){
   $(this).removeClass('is-hover');
});
```

```css
.is-hover .heading {
  background: red;
}

.is-hover .excerpt {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <header class="heading"><h2>CIAO</h2></header>
   <div>don't change me</div>
   <div class="excerpt">text text text</div>
 </div>




  <div>
     <header class="heading"><h2>hi!</h2></header>
     <div>don't change me</div>
     <div class="excerpt">text two text two</div>
  </div>
```